# Create a random column based on value from a column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a random sample column based on a column in the same table on partition by COLUMNA, COLUMNB and COLUMNC. I need to use the NO_OF_SAMPLE column in order to determine the number of records that I need a sample for.

[image: sample data]

Comment: How does the randomness of the sample relate to 3 columns? If it's random it won't be based on any of the data in the table. If it's not random then what are the rules for determining why the three columns influence the `RANDOMSAMPLE` column?

Comment: It isn't clear whence the source of the values in the random sample column is.  Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: Also, please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @Ben So its random inside a particular label for example we need to take one random row out of all the X values in columnB , 2 rows out of all the Y values and 3 rows out of all the z values. Do let me know if i was clear

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the source is the 4th column "NO_OF SAMPLE"

Comment: @Aleksej Sorry the "Y" flags in the 5th column was not aligning that is why put a screenshot.Sorry

Comment: You wrote in your question that you wanted it based on 3 columns, but your comment says you only want it on COLUMNB. Is this the case?

Comment: @Ben In the above example value in columnA doesn't change therefore my explanation seems to be based on only columnB. Sorry for misleading

Comment: @Gordon Linoff
What if the no_of_samples column is as below NO_OF_SAMPLE 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a column called `no_of_sample` which seems to indicate the number of `X`/`Y` combinations you want.

If this is the case, you can do what you want with `row_number()` and `dbms_random.value()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(no_of_sample) over (partition by columnA, columnB) as max_num,
             row_number() over (partition by columnA, columnB order by dbms_random.value()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= max_num;
```

Comment: will test this out with actual data.Thanks